# JQuery - Get all inner elements with jquery and modify CSS of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get via JQuery all the inner elements of a div and then modify their CSS. I have this:

```
<div id="example">
    <div class="inner"><p>Hello</p>
    <div class="inner"><p>I'm</p>
    <div class="inner"><p>New in JQuery</p>
</div>
```

Then I want to use a JQuery to change their CSS. Something like this:

Inside the

```
$('#example').on('click', function(){
     $(this).html().css('color','blue');
});
```

It's an example but I want to apply this to a real web application using drag and drop. Thanks

Comment: Do `$('#example').on('click', function(){`

Comment: `$(this).css('color','blue');` instead of `$(this).html().css('color','blue');`

Comment: Yes, it's only an examl¿ple, my question is how to select them and modify as JQuery objects (:

Comment: That only will modify the #example div, but I want a direct modification to the inner div's!

Answer (score 0):

$.children() will get you any elements that are direct descendants of your selector. If you want to get ALL decendants, you can do $.find(). It sounds like you want to do this:

```
$("#example").click(function () {
    $(this).children().css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yQh4G/)

Answer (score 0):

On click it'll change color to red.

```
 $('#example').on('click', function(){
    $( this ).css( "color", "red" );
 });
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67Lax/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use .on function try this:

```
$("#example div").on("click", function(){
  $(this).css('color','blue');
});
```

Js Fiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aAuMU/)